# Title is not defined JS, ReferenceError: title is not defined

Tags: javascript

I need help, I'm developing a site with opeenstreetmaps, I have all the code done but it gives me an error in the title that is not defined not letting me pull what was stored in the title follows the code,
already tried many things but always the error in the title, the variable is an array and always right not the error in it only in title.

```
     function mstMuc(){      
              bounds = [];
              bounds = L.latLngBounds();
              for (var i=0; i < dtMuc[0].length; i++){ //adicionando simucs no mapa
                url = L.icon({
                  iconUrl:icoMuc[dtMuc[3][i]],
                  iconSize: [20,20],
                  iconAnchor: [13,5],
                  popupAnchor: [13,5]
              });
                marker = L.marker([dtMuc[1][i],dtMuc[2][i]],{icon:url}, 
                {title:dtMuc[3][i]}).addTo(map).on('click', onClick);
                function onClick (e){
                  nmuc = this.option.title;
                  alert(nmuc);
                }
                arMuc[i] = marker;
                bounds.extend([dtMuc[1][i],dtMuc[2][i]]);
                map.fitBounds(bounds);
                getdate(2);
                };
```